# Where is Postgres 9.1 log located by default in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, logging, ubuntu

Where I can find startup log of of my postgres 9.1 server.
I'm using Ubuntu. 
`postgres restart` gets failed.
`find / -name pg_log` founds nothing
standard log at `/etc/postgres/main/9.1/` is clear

Comment: See `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RedHat like distributions it would be in `/var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log` or look for the variable `PGLOG` in the init script in `/etc/init.d/postgresql`

Comment: No variable PGLOG, and no file psstartup.log in system

Comment: @Evl-ntnt Did you find the init script? If so look at the `start()` function to know which variable contains the startup log file name. Then search for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu it is one of the files in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_log/`.